# How to sort a dataframe according to one of the columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I have some portion of the dataframe:

```
Hospital.Name                           State heart attack heart failure pneumonia
270                   ST ROSE HOSPITAL    CA         15.3          10.6      10.3
271                 ST JOSEPH HOSPITAL    CA         18.6          14.4      11.9
272           PENINSULA MEDICAL CENTER    CA         16.0          11.8      10.4
274 QUEEN OF THE VALLEY MEDICAL CENTER    CA         16.1          11.9      11.1
275                 ST HELENA HOSPITAL    CA         16.6          11.2       9.3
276             SUTTER AMADOR HOSPITAL    CA         16.0          15.8      12.7
```

I want to sort the rows according to one of the outcomes heart attack or heart failure or pneumonia

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a dataframe by multiple column(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-multiple-columns)

Comment: Are you looking for `df[order(df$heart.attack),]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read data:

```
t <- read.table(header=TRUE, sep=",", text="row, Hospital.Name,  State, heart attack, heart failure, pneumonia
270,                   ST ROSE HOSPITAL,    CA,        15.3,         10.6,            10.3
271,                 ST JOSEPH HOSPITAL,    CA,         18.6,          14.4,      11.9
272,           PENINSULA MEDICAL CENTER,    CA,         16.0,          11.8,      10.4
274, QUEEN OF THE VALLEY MEDICAL CENTER,    CA,         16.1,          11.9,      11.1
275,                 ST HELENA HOSPITAL,    CA,         16.6,          11.2,       9.3
276,             SUTTER AMADOR HOSPITAL,    CA,         16.0,          15.8,      12.7")
```

sort by `pneumonia`

```
t2 <- t[order(t$pneumonia),]
print(t2)
```

sort by `heart.failure`

```
t3 <- t[order(t$heart.failure),]
print(t2)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
    arrange(heart.failure)
```